# I can't figure out why ClusterRole wasn't created

Tags: kubernetes

I'm studying kubernetes cluster's authorization.

I'm using minikube cluster now, and its version is v1.13.2.

And I'm trying to create ClusterRole with aggregation feature, so child ClusterRole can receive parent ClusterRole's rules.

Here is my .yaml file's contents.

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: parent-clusterrole
  labels:
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-child-clusterrole: "true"
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["nodes"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: child-clusterrole
aggregationRule:
  clusterRoleSelectors:
  - matchLabels:
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-child-clusterrole: "true"
rules: []
```

When I tried to create resources with `kubectl apply -f {file-name}`, I received the result below.

```bash
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/parent-clusterrole created
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "clusterrole-aggregation.yaml": ClusterRole in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ClusterRole: strict decoding error: unknown field "aggregationRule.clusterRoleSelectors[0].rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-child-clusterrole"
```

Is there a wrong thing that I couldn't catch?

Comment: Should it be indented two more spaces underneath `- matchLabels:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  ...
  aggregationRule:
    clusterRoleSelectors:
    - matchLabels:
        rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-child-clusterrole: "true"  # <-- ident with 2 spaces required
```